# can we deploy a .war file in simple website cPanel?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, cpanel

Is it possible to deploy a java web application using Hibernate and Spring MVC to a simple website cPanel-> File Manager as we deploy a simple php/mysql application?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot you can build jar with embedded Servlet container, so Java runtime has to be available at minimum.

Amount of RAM available on shared hosting PHP services is often pretty low, so may not be enough for your needs. To find hosting for your Java/Spring application, pick hosting services that specialize on Java/Servlets.

Also if you are planning to rely your business on such application you should avoid shared hosting as same machine is aggregated between various users. So aggregated users can degrade performance of your application.

Comment: Can we deploy it inside the Cloud Application in godaddy?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to deploy war file into cPanel-> File Manager as we deploy a simple php/mysql application. But for that you required **tomcat in file manager** . Just zip the .war file and upload in manager directory and just extract that zip file.thats it!

Please refer this:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Deploy+Java+Applications